# I am unable to retrieve exact data from below statement

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT  ST_CODE.ST_NAME "CURRENT ST",
    ST_CODE.ST_NAME "PREVIOUS ST" FROM FLT_TBL       
    LEFT JOIN MT_ST_CODE ON
        FLT_TRN_TBL. PIS_DB_VER = MT_ST_CODE.VERSION AND
        FLT_TRN_TBL. CRNT_ST_CODE = MT_ST_CODE.ST_CODE
    LEFT JOIN MT_ST_CODE ON
        FLT_TRN_TBL. PIS_DB_VER = MT_ST_CODE.VERSION AND
        FLT_TRN_TBL. PREV_ST_CODE = MT_ST_CODE.ST_CODE
```

Comment: That's nice.  No doubt *you* know what you want returned.  And *you* know what your data looks like.  However, people reading the question do not have this information.

Comment: What data can't you retrieve (and what _can_ you retrieve) ?

Comment: I can retrieve same data for two column but i need it two separate data for 2 column for each row (It should not same data for current & privious)@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Is it running query? I think this query will throw error as `FLT_TRN_TBL` alias is unknown to the query.

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes:

- `FLT_TRN_TBL` is unknow alias
- `ST_CODE` is unknown alias
- you must give alias to `MT_ST_CODE`

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT M1.ST_NAME "CURRENT ST",
       M2.ST_NAME "PREVIOUS ST" 
  FROM FLT_TBL FLT_TRN_TBL     
LEFT JOIN MT_ST_CODE M1 ON
        FLT_TRN_TBL.PIS_DB_VER = M1.VERSION AND
        FLT_TRN_TBL.CRNT_ST_CODE = M1.ST_CODE
LEFT JOIN MT_ST_CODE M2 ON
        FLT_TRN_TBL.PIS_DB_VER = M2.VERSION AND
        FLT_TRN_TBL.PREV_ST_CODE = M2.ST_CODE
```

Or Try using group by instead of multiple joins as following:

```
SELECT FLT_TRN_TBL.PIS_DB_VER 
       Max(case when FLT_TRN_TBL.CRNT_ST_CODE = MT_ST_CODE.ST_CODE then  MT_ST_CODE.ST_NAME end) as "CURRENT ST",
       Max(case when FLT_TRN_TBL.PREV_ST_CODE = MT_ST_CODE.ST_CODE then MT_ST_CODE.ST_NAME end) as "PREVIOUS ST" 
  FROM FLT_TBL  FLT_TRN_TBL
LEFT JOIN MT_ST_CODE 
  ON FLT_TRN_TBL.PIS_DB_VER = MT_ST_CODE.VERSION
Group by FLT_TRN_TBL.PIS_DB_VER
```

Cheers!!